# How to remove the service from the manager in docker swarm

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm

What I want to do is remove the service of the specific Docker Swarm manager.

E.g: I want Manager 1 and Manager 3 to only the one who can able to access my webservice.

My problem right now is that Manager 1, 2, 3 can access my services.

I just want to 1 and 3 to be able to do so without removing 2 from the Docker Swarm.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "access my webservice"? Are you trying to control where the service runs, or disable the ingress networking, or completely disable overlay networking?

Comment: For example. 
in my browser I type 10.10.5.242 for manager1 and 10.10.5.5.243 for manager 3 and then for manager 2 the ip is 10.10.5.233.
and all of those 3 can access my webserver for example tomcat.
what i do first is I created a services for my swarm.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

To disable ingress networking, define your published ports with the long syntax with the mode set to `host`. This will only publish the port on the host where the service runs. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1

```
ports:
 - target: 80
   published: 8080
   protocol: tcp
   mode: host
```

---

If you want the service available on a group of nodes, I'd recommend creating a label on the nodes where you want to run the service, configure the service with a constraint on that label, and schedule the service in global mode instead of replicated.

`docker node update --label-add myapp=true node1`

Configure the constraint and scheduling mode in the deploy section:

```
deploy:
  mode: global
  placement:
    constraint:
      - node.labels.myapp == true
```

See the deploy section reference for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint

---

To run this with a `docker service create` command, the syntax would look like:

```
docker service create \
  --publish published=8080,target=80,mode=host,protocol=tcp \
  --mode global \
  --constraint 'node.labels.myapp == true' \
  ...
```

That can be a handful to type, so I'd recommending using a compose.yml file and deploying with a `docker stack deploy -c compose.yml $stack_name` instead.

Comment: docker service create -p 9090:8080 --name ojt-ian-integrate --constraint node.hostname=="toromanger1" --restart-max-attempts 5 toro-ian

what i've done so far is this

Comment: deploy section? do you mean i will add that in the docker file?

Comment: You can use Docker Compose files to deploy stacks on a swarm. The deploy section is where you configure swarm deployment settings. If you are using `docker service create`, to set host mode port publishing you change `-p 9090:8080` to `-p mode=host,target=8080,published=9090`